# How durable are the Raspberry Pi and the Raspberry Pi Camera?

Tags: camera, pi-3b+, temperature

I plan to use my Pi and the Pi camera v2 no IR version as a wildlife camera. Now my question is can I run the camera in the winter (maybe -10 degrees Celsius) and will it still work like the Raspberry Pi? My other question is can the Raspberry + camera survive some dust?

Comment: run a test inside your freezer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi devices themselves do not have any proper [International Protection Rating](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_(stopie%C5%84_ochrony)), therefore device itself is not recommended for such usage. From my own experiences, Raspberry Pi devices can survive temperatures as low as -20°C(at least one in my backpack worked well) but need to be treated as a bare motherboards - with great care, far from any dust/electricity conducting materials. I'd suggest finding proper case for the Pi AND the camera before risking the damage.